# HBase HTable jar | ClassNotFoundException

Tags: jar, hbase

I am running a map-reduce job which crashes with a `ClassNotFoundException` for class `HTable`. This is weird because I am specifying all hbase jars. So I checked whether HTable is defined in any of the jars. In the folder where all jars were stored, I ran the following shell script.

```
for j in `ls *.jar`
do
jar tf $j | grep HTable
done
```

The result was blank. So it did not find HTable in these jars. Is it possible that the HTable definition might be in a jar within a jar and my method does not look into nested jars? I am surprised because these jars reside in the `hbase-<version>/lib` folder and so must have a definition of HTable.

How do I check whether a class exist in a (possibly) nested jar file?

Answer (score 0):

I found it in `hbase-client-<version>.jar`. I am using CDH 5, so that JAR can be found [here](http://repository.cloudera.com/cloudera/libs-release-local/org/apache/hbase/hbase-client/0.96.1.1-cdh5.0.1/). Hope this helps!